# When does a matrix game and the sign flipped matrix game have the same nash equilibria?

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Given a game $G$, we can construct another $G'$, by a positive scaling i.e. $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$, s.t. each entry of $A$ is scaled by $\lambda$

Obviously, $G$ and $G'$ have the same nash strategy. We have simply uniformly increased the payoff of every strategy.

What if we flip the sign of every single payoff entry?

Intuitively, this implies a change from each "payoff" to "cost". In the first game without the sign change, the nash strategy maximizes each player's payoff. In the second game with a sign change, the nash strategy minimizes each player's cost. So the nash strategies should be equivalent.

Does this intuition hold for all normal form/matrix games?

What if we restrict our attention to zero sum games or symmetric games??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(After edit, thanks @Robert Israel) If the payoff is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
(1,1) & (0,0) \\
(0,0) & (-1,-1)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then the only Nash equilibrium is to play strategy 1 for both players, which changes when you change the signs. Maximizing profit may be equivalent to minimizing cost, but it is definitely *not* equivalent to *maximizing cost*.

However, for zero-sum games represented by symmetric matrices, something like that may be true.

Comment: For zero-sum games, how does changing the sign "reverse the players"? 
It can change the nature of the optimal strategies completely.  For example
$$ \pmatrix{1 & -1 & -2\cr -1 & 1 & -2\cr 2 & 2 & 0\cr}$$ has a saddle point, but for $$ \pmatrix{-1 & 1 & 2\cr 1 & -1 & 2\cr -2 & -2 & 0\cr}$$ the optimal strategies are mixtures $(1/2, 1/2, 0)$.

Comment: Right, thank you. I was thinking about changing signs and transposing :). But zero-sum game and symmetric matrix is enough, right?